# Listing longest file path with C#

Tags: c#, .net, command

I am using Windows XP. I need to find out the file (in folder D:\Test)  with longest path (path length + filename length).  How can we find out this using C#?

**Is there any command like dir, tree ect for to verify this?**
Any idea how to do it using T-SQL?

Note: xp_cmdshell can be used frm T-SQL to get the directory structure

Thanks

Lijo

Comment: SQL? Wth would SQL do for you? It is used with databases.

Comment: why do you want to do this? homework assignment?

Comment: @Lijo, just because you _can_ do it with SQL doesn't mean you should :) Kinda like building a car with an ice cream scoop. Well, yea, I guess you _could_ do it...  but why?

Comment: @jb. Do I get to keep the ice cream?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Using c# you could use the following snippet to retrieve the file with the longest name:

```
System.IO.Directory
  .GetFiles("D:\\Test", "*", SearchOption.AllDirectories)
  .OrderByDescending(p => p.Length)
  .FirstOrDefault()
```

You could validate the output with this PowerShell script:

```
Get-ChildItem | % { $_.FullName } | Sort-Object -Descending -Property Length
```

I don't know how to do this in T-SQL. However, I don't know why one want to do that.

Comment: Nice one, I really need to get more into that lambda-stuff.

Comment: @Lijo, are there any files in the diretory? `FirstOrDefault()` will return null if there are no files returned by `GetFiles()`. Do you have enough permissions?

Comment: @Lijo, yes, use `SearchOption.AllDirectories`. Updated my answer.

Comment: @Lijo, my bad: `GetFiles(string, string, SearchOption)` where the second parameter is the _searchPattern_. "*" will match all items.

Comment: Thanks .. String strings = System.IO.Directory.GetFiles("D:\\TFSLocation", "*", SearchOption.AllDirectories).OrderByDescending(p => p.Length).FirstOrDefault();  I do not have permission for powershell. Is there any other command??

Answer (score 0):

SQL has absolutely nothing to do with this. start by reading about the `DirectoryInfo` class [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.directoryinfo.aspx)

Comment: xp_cmdshell can be used frm T-SQL to get the directory structure

Comment: Maybe on the server's side. which is obviously not what the OP is looking for. Thanks for the -1.

Answer (score 0):

Use the DirectoryInfo class from System.IO namespace to get all files
iterate through these filenames and check if the length is bigger then what is previously found.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this will do it:

```
private static string getLongestFilename(string path)
{
    int maxLength = 0;
    string longestFile = string.Empty;
    DirectoryInfo di = new DirectoryInfo(path);
    foreach (FileInfo fi in di.GetFiles())
    {
        if (fi.FullName.Length > maxLength)
        {
            longestFile = fi.FullName;
            maxLength = fi.FullName.Length;
        }
    }
    return longestFile;
}
```

It will only return the first longest filename, but you get the idea.